# How to make a custom snapshot of non-system related stuff and be able to restore without reboot?

Tags: backup, restore, snapshot

I've looked through the past threads but couldn't find anything.

I'm looking for the tool or solution that makes a snapshot of a system state (it doesn't have to be everything, but I could specify where to snapshot) and ability to restore to that given snapshot without ubuntu restart.

As I don't need to snapshot system files, so I hope this is possible to restore to a given snapshot point without a restart.

To be more clear, let's say, before working with files, that can be removed, moved or updated I will make a snapshot of the specified path(s) and name that snapshot with a timestamp it is made. Then if it happens I did a mess, I can easily restore to a given snapshot point.

I'm looking for a solution besides `git` and alike tools.

I also wonder if that tool can remember previous state of MySQL database, otherwise I will just have a dump of it at some point.

Comment: "stuff" and "system state" are not clear. Do you want to snapshot the filesystem? The running programs and memory? What exactly do you want to be able to restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm).  This is a disk abstraction layer unlike the partitions you've been using until now and actually replaces them.

LVM has built-in snapshots which allows you to freeze an existing Logical Volume in time, at any moment, even while the system is running. You can continue to use the original volume normally, but the snapshot volume appears to be an image of the original, frozen in time at the moment you created it. You can use this to get a consistent filesystem image to back up, without shutting down the system. You can also use it to save the state of the system, so that you can later return to that state if you mess things up. You can even mount the snapshot volume and make changes to it, without affecting the original.

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Thanks. :) Maybe LVM is good, but you will need to re-install Linux to enable this. This won't work for already installed Linux, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Actually, that would be an [excellent new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  Meaning: I've never tried to do this afterwards...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `snapper`?

```
sudo apt-get snapper
```

[manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/snapper.8.html](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/snapper.8.html)

I haven't tried it but it looks promising

Comment: It seems the docs are not good for this package.

Comment: @oscar not great but http://snapper.io/manpages/snapper-configs.html also http://snapper.io/tutorial.html and the best part is that you don't need to be running btrfs

Comment: When I run: `sudo snapper -c home create-config /home`
It gives me error `Creating config failed (/sbin/chsnap not installed).`
Googling for that for ubuntu gives no results. This is Suse based program initially.

Comment: Maybe there a repo from the OBS that has a DEB version of snapper with that missing part